# How can I use Twig files in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, twig, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel, I have downloaded Twig files from website. But I don't know how to use this, because I have used only blade files.

Comment: For a question like this, you could [search for 'PHP Laravel Twig'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+laravel+twig). Please get into the habit of searching before asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a composer package [TwigBridge](https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge) to use TWIG templating instead for BLADE.